# Attempting to calculate absolute change and % change in 1 query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm having trouble with the SELECT portion of this query. I can calculate the absolute change just fine, but when I want to also find out the percent change I get lost in all the subqueries. Using BigQuery. Thank you!

```
SELECT  
 station_name, 
 ridership_2013, 
 ridership_2014,
 absolute_change_2014 / ridership_2013 * 100 AS percent_change,
 (ridership_2014 - ridership_2013) AS absolute_change_2014,
```

Comment: Your query has no subqueries, so your question is rather confusing.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Yes that's what I need help with: the subqueries. How would I write them in this case? My desired result is in the post title: I'm trying to calculate absolute growth and  % growth in the same select statement. The dataset is New York subway ridership from the years 2013 and 2014.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably be beneficial to organize your query with CTEs and descriptive aliases to make things a bit easier.  For example...

```
with 
data as (select * from project.dataset.table),
ridership_by_year as (
    select
        extract(year from ride_date) as yr,
        count(*) as rides
    from data
    group by 1
),
ridership_by_year_and_station as (
    select
        extract(year from ride_date) as yr,
        station_name,
        count(*) as rides
    from data
    group by 1,2
),
yearly_changes as (
    select 
        this_year.yr,
        this_year.rides,
        prev_year.rides as prev_year_rides,
        this_year.rides - coalesce(prev_year.rides,0) as absolute_change_in_rides,
        safe_divide( this_year.rides - coalesce(prev_year.rides), prev_year.rides) as relative_change_in_rides
    from ridership_by_year this_year
    left join ridership_by_year prev_year on this_year.yr = prev_year.yr + 1
),
yearly_station_changes as (
    select 
        this_year.yr,
        this_year.station_name,
        this_year.rides,
        prev_year.rides as prev_year_rides,
        this_year.rides - coalesce(prev_year.rides,0) as absolute_change_in_rides,
        safe_divide( this_year.rides - coalesce(prev_year.rides), prev_year.rides) as relative_change_in_rides
    from ridership_by_year this_year
    left join ridership_by_year prev_year on this_year.yr = prev_year.yr + 1
)
select * from yearly_changes
--select * from yearly_station_changes
```

Yes this is a bit longer, but IMO it is much easier to understand.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your query at all. The problem I'm having is simply that the column absolute_change_2014 isn't recognized where it's divided by ridership 2013. This is because that column doesn't exist until it's calculated, so I need to have (ridership_2014 - ridership_2013) AS absolute_change_2014 execute BEFORE the rest of the query, presumably with a subquery. But I don't know how to write it out. Where do I put the ( )?

Comment: Well, considering how poorly your question is written, I had to take some liberties.  Regardless, consider re-organizing your subqueries as CTEs as I have done, it makes it very easy to see where each field is coming from.

Comment: Wow, I don't think I said anything that deserves such a rude response. You are giving me a poor impression of the userbase on this site. Please keep in mind that people who post questions here are just learning. This stuff is new to us, and there's potentially a lot we still don't know. If you can't have some patience then just please don't respond to my questions. I don't know what CTEs are but I will try looking that up. Thanks, I guess?